# Cannot read property "texture" from undefined

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I know it is a very commonly asked question. I am getting a Cannot read property "texture" from undefined.Sorry I am pretty new to javascript.

The javascript part my code is as follows

```
this.createTexture=function(Texturename,width,height){
  this.Texture[Texturename]=gl.createTexture();
  this.Texture[Texturename].name=Texturename;
  this.Texture[Texturename].width=width;
  this.Texture[Texturename].height=height;
  return this.Texture[Texturename,width,height];
}
```

I am trying to create my texture in the webgl part.

How can I possibly call createTexture in webgl? where I can just enter the texturename, width and height and get the the function to work. I am aware this wont just create a texture but its just a simple example. I tried but ca

```
function exampleTexture(){
Texture.createTexture("moon",1024,1024);
}
```

It says my error is in the line

```
this.Texture[Texturename]=gl.createTexture();
```

Thanks

Comment: Does `Texture.Texture` exist? You're getting `this.Texture`, and `this` is the value of the object whose method is invoked. For `Texture.createTexture`, the value of `this` is `Texture`, so `this.Texture` is `Texture.Texture`. I don't fully understand what your code does, so I can't suggest a solution, however. Maybe you wanted to do `Texture[Texturename]`, in which case you should do `this[Texturename]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object, that are referred by `this`, seems to not have `Texture` property. In this case:

```
this.createTexture=function(Texturename,width,height){
  // use this.Texture if available, otherwise init it as an empty object
  this.Texture = this.Texture || {};

  this.Texture[Texturename]=gl.createTexture();
  this.Texture[Texturename].name=Texturename;
  this.Texture[Texturename].width=width;
  this.Texture[Texturename].height=height;
  return this.Texture[Texturename,width,height];
}
```

Note on the naming convention: in JS camelCase is typically used for variables, PascalCase for constructors. So I would rename `this.Texture` to `this.textures` and `Texturename` to `textureName`.